# work with dynamic element JQuery

Tags: jquery

My code creates dynamic divs. My function should work with these dynamic elements.

In HTML:

```
<div id="test">

</div>
```

In JQuery, I create few divs:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  $("#test").append("<div class=\"lists\" style=\"width=... height=...\"></div>");
}
```

In result, when I click on a div, an alert should be displayed. But this is not happening.

```
$(".lists").click(function () {
  alert("Hi");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#test").on("click", ".lists", function () {
  alert("Hi");
});
```